# How to use VBA to count the number of days interval?

Tags: excel, vba

[image]

How can I use VBA to find out the days interval? For the same num, can i count the number of dates between the first and the last date?

For example, I want to display the number of days '886000' took based on the first and the last date, it took 7 days and how can i display it on column J 'Interval'?

Comment: Do you need a VBA solution (and if so what have you tried)? What version of Excel do you have? (asking since this is doable with a formula)

Comment: @BigBen I'm using Excel 2016 and VBA solution is recommended but if formula works then its great

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using Excel 2016, take advantage of `MAXIFS` and `MINIFS`.

```
=MAXIFS(I:I,H:H,H1)-MINIFS(I:I,H:H,H1)+1
```

[image]

If those formulas are not available, alternately use `MAX` and `IF` within an array formula, entered using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
=MAX(IF($H$1:$H$9=H1,$I$1:$I$9))-MIN(IF($H$1:$H$9=H1,$I$1:$I$9))+1
```

[image]

Comment: It gives me #NAME? value

Comment: I just realized that [`MAXIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/maxifs-function-dfd611e6-da2c-488a-919b-9b6376b28883) and [`MINIFS`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599) are only available with an Office 365 subscription. I'll tweak the answer.

Comment: How can i make the count appear at the last row of the date, for e.g. for 888600 make the count appear on J9 instead

Comment: Maybe `=IF(COUNTIF($H$1:H1,H1)=COUNTIF($H$1:$H$9,H1),MAX(IF($H$1:$H$9=H1,$I$1:$I$9))-MIN(IF($H$1:$H$9=H1,$I$1:$I$9))+1,"")` (still enter with CSE and drag down as needed). This will return a blank string until the last instance of `888600`.